# React material Ui tooltip with list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xZoX.jpg)

I want to implement react material ui tooltip with customizes tooltip component .
which will use tooltip ,list item,list component from react material ui

I tried using list item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install MUI dependencies
   cd into project root directory and run `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`  and `npm install @mui/icons-material`
2. Import the required components

```js
import { Box, List, Tooltip, ListItem, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText, Divider } from '@mui/material';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import ModeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mode';
import * as React from 'react';
```

3. Write the List component
   From https://mui.com/material-ui/react-list/ and [https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/\](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/%5C)
   The two first item have a tooltip here : "Inbox" and 'Drafts"

```js
export default function BasicList() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
        <List>
          <Tooltip title="Inbox">
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <MailIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
            </Tooltip>
          <Tooltip title="Drafts">
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <ModeIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          </Tooltip>
        </List>
      <Divider />
        <List>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemText primary="Trash" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem disablePadding>
            <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
              <ListItemText primary="Spam" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: How is this valid HTML when you're using a tooltip directly nested within an `<ul>`? I received numerous warnings for doing this.